# Drawing isometric from two orthographic views

Tags: drawings

I'm having a trouble drawing this isometric shape.
I hope to find the drawing for this shape. ( would be so grateful if it's drawn in that isometric cube where each square of the cube is one unit of the dimensions )
[image]

Edit:
My try according to my understanding to the answer of @kamran
[image]

Is it correct ?

Comment: @joojaa It's not duplicate. The shapes are completely different

Comment: well the other option is to close this as offtopic since this is not a do my work for me or request favoirs site. Atleast as the duplicate tells you how to do it.

Comment: in anycase your object is far simpler

Comment: Well, I'm a beginner with drawing isometric from two orthographic views. I had drawn some other shapes, but I couldn't draw this, so can you help explaining how to draw it ?

Comment: draw a isometric square with 7x9 unit size. Shift 9 units down draw a 13 x 9 square. connect the corners. Now the most complicated part is done.

Comment: @joojaa that is a clear answer showing the process - well done : should help the OP sort out any issues.

Comment: That grid on your answer makes it so a 5 year old can do it - we had to use a 2H pencil and lightly draw the 3 axes ...

Comment: @SolarMike I'm still studying engineering drawing on paper and didn't work on any applications like autoCAD, so I'm asking if it's correct or not ?

Comment: There is an error in your drawing, the T connecting line on the back has same direction as the one in front. [See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6milk.png)

Comment: May you please correct it with a picture ?
I couldn't understand it :(

Comment: @Youssef13 there is a picture in the previous  comment see the "See this" text is a link (which is why it has a different color) click on it.

Comment: @SolarMike i tested this on my kids and to be honest the 5 year old had some big conceptual problems. However the 8 year old had no problem.

Comment: @joojaa not a bad guess then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close!

[image]

*Figure 1. The error.*

Since there is no hidden line on the cut-away face then that edge must be in-line with the front edge. Project the bottom corner straight back as shown.

Answer (score 1):

I can help you imagine its shape and leave the actual drawing to you.

This shape was a basic 13x9x9 cube. They first cut from the bottom face a channel of 5x3, then they chamfered (cut to an angle) one side, making it to a slope!

Then they cut a trapezoid prism from top right and left side of the object but not all the way.

May be if you consider the side view as front view, and front view as side view it can help!

Comment: I edited the question and added my try for drawing it. May you please look at it and tell me if there are any mistakes ?